# what's the right way of joning two tables, group by a column, and select only one row for each record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a crews table

```
           CREATE TABLE crew(crew_id INT, crew_name nvarchar(20), )
```

And a time log table, which is just a very long list of actions performed by the crew

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeLog](
[time_log_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[experiment_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[crew_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[starting] [bit] NULL,
[ending] [bit] NULL,
[exception] [nchar](10) NULL,
[sim_time] [time](7) NULL,
    [duration] [int] NULL,
[real_time] [datetime] NOT NULL )
```

I want to have a view that shows only one row for each crew with the latest sim_time + duration .

Is a view the way to go? If yes, how do I write it? If not, what's the best way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a query to select what you want:

```
select * from (
    select 
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by c.crew_id order by l.sim_time desc) as rNum
    from crew as c
    inner join TileLog as l (on c.crew_id = l.crew_id)
) as t
where rNum = 1
```

Comment: `partition by c.crew_id`, not `creq_id `

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you need that data for.
anyway, a simple query to find latest sim time would be something like

```
select C.*, TL.sim_time 
from crew C /*left? right? inner?*/ join TimeLog TL on TL.crew_id = C.crew.id
where TL.sim_time in (select max(timelog_subquery.sim_time) from TimeLog timelog_subquery where crew_id = C.crew_id )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. can you elaborate on the use of INNER ?

Comment: @ypercube- aggreed; changed that. @b3bel- timelog_subquery is a subquery which, for every crew_id, selects the TimeLog record with the maximal sim_time

Comment: will this subquery yield one result per each crew_id, or just the maximum independent of its crew id ?

Comment: it will actually be 1 result per each TimeLog record with the maximal sim_time and the same crew_id. Meaning- if there are 2 records with the same sim_time and same crew_id, then both will be returned by the query.